# Details view is giving me some problems as I am using a custom business logic layer and not a SQLDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, detailsview

I have a DetailsView that uses my Business Logic Layer in the code behind. I still use the DetailsView declaratively the same as if you drop a label control on the page but I don't declare a datasourceID in the attributes section of the XHTML.

After extensive searching on the web I noticed that most examples use a SqlDataSource declaratively and assign the id to the DetailsView datarouceID attribute.

I don't want to have the UI directly connected to the Data Logic Layer. I have a BLL that does all the busines end transactions and passes objects to the UI.

This is what my DetailsView looks like.

```
   <asp:DetailsView ID="dvCapability" 
                               runat="server" 
                               Width="90%" AutoGenerateEditButton="true"
                               AutoGenerateRows="False" 
                               EmptyDataText="Unable to retrieve the capability details." 
                               BorderColor="LightGray" 
                               BorderStyle="Solid" 
                               BorderWidth="1px" 
                               DataKeyNames="IAID" >
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="altrow" />
                <EmptyDataRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <Fields>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status:" HeaderStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-Width="85%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:Label ID="lblLabStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LabStatus") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddLabStatus" runat="server" Width="200px" BackColor="White" Font-Size="10px" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("LabStatus") %>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type:" HeaderStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-Width="85%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:Label ID="lblLabType" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LabType") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="tbLabType" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LabType") %>' Width="200px" BackColor="White" Enabled="false" Font-Size="10px" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UIC:" HeaderStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-Width="85%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:Label ID="lblUIC" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UIC") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddUIC" runat="server" Width="200px" BackColor="White" Font-Size="10px" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("UIC") %>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Org code:" HeaderStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-Width="85%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:Label ID="lblOrgCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("OrgCode") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddOrgCode" runat="server" Width="200px" BackColor="White" Font-Size="10px" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("OrgCode") %>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="VSYSCOM:" HeaderStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-Width="85%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:Label ID="lblVSYSCOM" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("VSYSCOM") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="tbVSYSCOM" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("VSYSCOM") %>' Width="200px" BackColor="White" Font-Size="10px" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name:" HeaderStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-Width="85%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:Label ID="lblLabName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LabName") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="tbLabName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LabName") %>' Width="500px" BackColor="White" Font-Size="10px" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description:" HeaderStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-Width="85%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:Label ID="lblLabDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LabDescription") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="tbLabDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LabDescription") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" Width="500px" Height="75px" BackColor="White" Font-Size="11px" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Technical Capability:" HeaderStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-Width="85%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:Label ID="lblTechnicalCapability" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TechnicalCapability") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="tbTechnicalCapability" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TechnicalCapability") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" Width="500px" Height="75px" BackColor="White" Font-Size="11px" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Facility:" HeaderStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-Width="85%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:Label ID="lblFacility" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Facility") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="tbFacility" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Facility") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" Width="500px" Height="75px" BackColor="White" Font-Size="11px" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Notes:" HeaderStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-Width="85%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:Label ID="lblComments" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Comments") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="tbComments" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Comments") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" Width="500px" Height="75px" BackColor="White" Font-Size="11px" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />
                </Fields>
                <FooterStyle CssClass="footer" />
                <HeaderStyle Width="15%" />
                <PagerStyle CssClass="footer" />
                <RowStyle CssClass="row" />
              </asp:DetailsView>
```

I bind it to a DataTable that is returned from my BLL in the Page's codebhind like so.

```
 Utilities.BindCompositeControl(dvCapability, Controller.GetCapability(getIaid()));
```

The BindCompositeControl() method is in a static class that I use to reduce redundatnt coding. The method is coded as follows:

```
public static void BindCompositeControl(CompositeDataBoundControl control, DataTable values)
        {
            control.DataSource = values;
            control.DataBind();
        }
```

However, when I try to use the Edit or Insert Buttons that are generated by the DetailsView control nothing happens. What am I missing in order to bind this control programatically and change it's operational state on the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can post your code for your data source you are binding, that will help see if you've allowed inserting and updating which may be causing an issue.

However I suspect you may need to manually maintain the datasource as you change the mode of the DetailsView. When you click Edit / Insert it causes a postback and I believe it no longer has the datasource attached.

On the first load of the control, you'll attach the datasource but after that you need to recreate the control each time, probably by saving the control state to the ViewState, recreating the data source and pull the control state back out of the ViewState on each page load.

It sounds more complex than it is. One way to do this is by creating the datasource through the OnInit event for the page. If you need to maintain selected rows or pages, use the ViewState to maintain those details.

You should create the DataSource and bind it before the ViewState is up, so create the datasource and apply it in OnInit

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);

    datatype myData = /* .... */
    //Create DataSource here
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        //Do something
        myData.add(/* some data */);
    }

    dvCapability.DataSource = myData;
    dvCapability.DataBind();
}
```

To add and delete items, you'll need to store the data in a way that is accessible to the rest of a page, such as Session[] and then remove / add items to that during the dvCapabilities_Inerting event, etc. After an add or delete you'll need to rebind the data with the updated data.

Take a gander at this http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx. This sort of explains things under the **2. Persisting static data** section.

Comment: Let me ask you this. The EnableviewState is automatically set to true by default. Should the DetailView not retain the information in the ViewState and repopulate the DetailsView from it or do I have to invoke a databinding method in order to do so? Or should I just handle the OnChanging event and call the BindCompositeControl method I have described above again?

Comment: Unfortunately you've come across the main confusing part of PostBack/ViewState. If you set the data source in the code behind, the data isn't placed in the ViewState and you must manually do that even if you have EnableViewState = true. Let me look for a site with a good explanation and update my answer with it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kirk. I've forgotten the nuances of viewstate and postback when it comes to databound controls. I used to experience this issue with the drop down list back several years ago. I was in the desktop software realm for the past 3 years and forgot some of the hurdles a stateless environment presents to us.

Comment: Client is definitely less confusing in terms of saving the state. Good luck with this.

Comment: This was a great resource. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx#viewstate_topic1 Overriding the Page.OnInit method worked. I write a value to the view state object to persist the details view mode. Then I retrieve it in the OnInit method and call detailsView.ChangeMode().

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who may run into this down the line. Here's what I came up with and it works. I add a value to the ViewState dictionary and set it in the Page_OnInit event handler. In the Page_PreRender event handler is where I bind the detailsview and set it's Mode. Please note that if you are using viewstate you must bind your data and change mode after the view state has loaded. the Page's Initialize method is called before the ViewState is loaded. Hope this helps those who need it. I found many posts that weren't successfully answered regarding this topic. Much thanks to **Kirk** for giving me a solid answer and a great lead on where I wanted to go.

```
public partial class About : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                //Initially add the view state variable
                ViewState.Add("DetailsViewMode", DetailsViewMode.ReadOnly);

            }
            base.OnInit(e);
        }

        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ViewState["DetailsViewMode"] != null)
            {
                //change the mode of the DetailsView
                dvTest.ChangeMode((DetailsViewMode)ViewState["DetailsViewMode"]);

                //Bind the details view to a source
                //This is my own custom class but this is where you yould put
                //DetailsView.Datasource = <source>
                //DetailsView.DataBind()
                Utilities.BindCompositeControl(dvTest, NadController.GetCapability(19));
            }

            base.OnPreRender(e);
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        //Must handle ModeChanging event or you'll get a run time error when binding DetailsView programatically
        protected void dvTest_ModeChanging(object sender, DetailsViewModeEventArgs e)
        { 
        }

        //Handles button clicks from the DetailsView control
        protected void dvTest_OnItemCommand(object sender, DetailsViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            ViewState["DetailsViewMode"] = GetDetailsViewMode(e.CommandName);
        }



        protected DetailsViewMode GetDetailsViewMode(string mode)
        {
            switch (mode)
            {
                case Constants.Edit:
                    return DetailsViewMode.Edit;
                case Constants.Insert:
                    return DetailsViewMode.Insert;
                default:
                    return DetailsViewMode.ReadOnly;
            }
        }
    }
```